# Firebase App is crashing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm following this tutorial:- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0ScnHJi8WY
and I don't know, why my app is crashing

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vks_apps.blogs.MainActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.vks_apps.blogs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_add)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,PostActivity.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_post.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.vks_apps.blogs.PostActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageSelect"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/add_btn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/titleField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSelect"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:hint="Post Title..."
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titleField"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_outline"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Post Description..."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Submit Post"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**PostActivity.java**

```
package com.vks_apps.blogs;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ImageButton mSelectImage;
    public static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri mImageUri = null;
    private EditText mPostTitle, mPostDesc;
    private Button mSubmitBtn;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        mSelectImage = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageSelect);
        mPostTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleField);
        mPostDesc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descField);
        mSubmitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        mSubmitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                startPosting();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startPosting()
    {
        mProgress.setMessage("Posting to Blog...");
        mProgress.show();

        String title_val = mPostTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String desc_val = mPostDesc.getText().toString().trim();

        if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(title_val)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(desc_val)) && (mImageUri != null))
        {
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Blog_Images").child(mImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(mImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {
            mImageUri = data.getData();
            mSelectImage.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        }
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vks_apps.blogs"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vks_apps.blogs">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PostActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**res/drawable/input_outline.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:color="@color/greyColor" android:width="1dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

**res/values/colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0488d1</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#0477bd</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="greyColor">#c2c2c2</color>
</resources>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
07-23 23:22:31.904 6461-6461/com.vks_apps.blogs D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                  --------- beginning of crash
07-23 23:22:31.904 6461-6461/com.vks_apps.blogs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.vks_apps.blogs, PID: 6461
                                                                  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac;
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.vks_apps.blogs.PostActivity.onCreate(PostActivity.java:42)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.vks_apps.blogs-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source) 
                                                                      at com.vks_apps.blogs.PostActivity.onCreate(PostActivity.java:42) 
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

PS: Don't mark this question as duplicate, as I've already tried all the other methods. Here I've written the original code without any modification. Also I've uploaded the video of my app's crashing - You can see it: http://www.mediafire.com/file/xb61s4k0wojxy2z/app.mp4

also I think it's happening because of this line :

```
mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

because when i remove this line, my app is working fine, but i need this line to upload the file

Comment: this is not an advertising but I would recommend you take Udacity courses

Comment: https://www.udacity.com/courses/android

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafiz Ok, I'll take udacity classes too, but right now help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FirebaseUI documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) contains a section on dependencies with the following warning and a table of compatible versions:

> If you are using any dependencies in your app of the form compile
>   'com.google.firebase:firebase-*:x.y.z' or compile
>   'com.google.android.gms:play-services-*:x.y.z' you need to make sure
>   that you use the same version that your chosen version of FirebaseUI
>   requires.

You are using version 10.0.1 of the Firebase libraries.  For those, you must use version 1.1.1 of the FirebaseUI components: `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.1.1`.

**Update:**

The problem may be a version incompatibility with the v26 support libs.  Try these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2' // CHANGED
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2' // CHANGED
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2' // CHANGED
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0' // CHANGED
```