# Glide for choosing image from folder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a profile for my android app however it crashes when i try to select an image from my photos on my phone so I have tried to implement Glide instead of bitmap. I am getting an error however

Code for profile and selecting image and save to firebase:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == CHOOSE_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        uriProfileImage = data.getData();

        //try {
            //Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uriProfileImage);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(uriProfileImage)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_camera))
                    .into(imageView);



            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

        //} catch (IOException e) {
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
    StorageReference profileImageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    if (uriProfileImage != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        profileImageUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE

App crashes as soon as i select an image from my folder on my phone

ERROR logcat:

```
06-24 13:24:12.435 20560-20560/net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth, PID: 20560
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac;
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source:11)
    at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.ProfileActivity.uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(ProfileActivity.java:271)
    at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:261)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4335)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4382)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth-rk3BCqC1GSgSTxz4HlhFDw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth-rk3BCqC1GSgSTxz4HlhFDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getInstance(Unknown Source:11) 
    at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.ProfileActivity.uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(ProfileActivity.java:271) 
    at net.simplifiedlearning.firebaseauth.ProfileActivity.onActivityResult(ProfileActivity.java:261) 
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7235) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4335) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4382) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: use the path of your image like `Uri selectedImageGallery = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    String imagePathGallery = getPath(selectedImageGallery);  Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imagePathGallery)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_camera)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(imageView);`

Comment: in your onActivityResult instead of this `Glide.with(this)
                    .load(uriProfileImage)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_camera)
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(imageView);`

Comment: I am still getting errors with imageReturnedIntent, getPath and dontAnimate()

Comment: I have updated code above

Comment: according to this link (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44199289/9981067) Glide has an issue and you should use is like this `Glide
 .with(this)
 .load(uriProfileImage)
 .apply(new RequestOptions()
 .placeholder(R.mipmap.icon_camera)
 .fitCenter()
 .into(mUserImage);`

Comment: dontAnimate() still comes with error unfortunately

Comment: just remove `.dontAnimate()` from your glide.

Comment: App crashes as soon as i select an image from my phone

Comment: may I see your log?

Comment: updated above..

Comment: looks like this link contain a solution for your firebase problem (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45268855/9981067)